# Accessing 2 windows machines on network without IP address and using internet as well

Tags: windows, networking, authentication

I have one windows 7 professional and one windows 7 ultimate machines. 
When I try to connect each other on network, them ask username and password, 
even I have "Turn off password protected sharing" for "Home or work" and also for "Public"
in "Change advanced sharing settings".

When I define IP address on both these machines are accessiable to each other but not internet is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In the Gateway field, in the same menu where you assigned the IP address of your PCs, you need to put the IP of the router that is connected to the Internet.